# firebase android functional setup

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Added firebase to my android marshmallow application and have run the application with the recommended FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("")) to verify the setup and am getting the report in my firebase console. 
Questions due to the developer guide being a bit unclear:

1. do I need to add a firebase.log or firebase.logcat to each of the caught exceptions in my application in order to get report entries for them. If so, which is recommended?  Should I use firebasecrash.report instead?
2. Is there any additional work needed to capture uncaught exceptions generated

In the evaluation phase at this point and would prefer not to make a lot of code changes for something that might not work out.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of Firebase Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#create_your_first_error) (I added numbers to correlate them to your questions):

> Firebase Crash Reporting automatically generates reports for fatal errors (or uncaught exceptions) (2). However, you can also generate reports in instances where you catch an exception but still want to report the occurrence (1).

So:

1. if you want to report caught exception you have to report them yourself with `FirebaseCrash.report()`.
2. uncaught exceptions are reported automatically.

Comment: This contradicts what I'm seeing with testing.  Code makes a firebasecrash.report in a catch and have yet to see an entry in the console report.